# Função para verificar se muda o ano

Tags: c#, datetime, data

Eu tenho este código que quase que funciona perfeitamente.

Fui fazer um teste, e quando chega para gerar em janeiro, ele gera para o mesmo ano, exemplo ele gerou uma fatura para `15/12/2019` e tem mais duas para gerar, ele gera o mês correto, e o ano errado
`15/01/2019` e `15/02/2019` sendo que ele deveria mudar o ano.
Como posso comparar?

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= parcelas; i++)
                {
                    var idfatura = db.FaturaContasReceberP.Max(b => b.Id);

                    var venc = new FaturaContasReceber
                    {
                        FaturaContasReceberPId = idfatura,
                        DataFatura = DateTime.Now,
                        DiasAtraso = totalDia,
                        Data = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + "/" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 1).ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")),
                        DataPagamento = datapagamento,
                        Valor = valor1,
                        Total = saldo,
                        Saldo = saldo,
                        Quitado = quitado,
                        Caixa = caixa,
                    };
                    db.Add(venc);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    saldo = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer somar meses à data atual, basta fazer:

```
Data = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i - 1);
```

---

Quando você faz `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd") + "/" + ...`, você está criando uma string. Em seguida, `DateTime.Parse` transforma esta string em um `DateTime`.

Mas toda essa volta não é necessária, pois `AddMonths` já retorna outro `DateTime` com os meses somados.

Além disso, na string que você está montando, somente o mês tem seu valor alterado, enquanto o ano sempre permanece o mesmo. Já usando `AddMonths`, já é verificado automaticamente se precisa mudar o ano ou não.

---

Só lembrando que há alguns detalhes a se atentar quando for somar um mês. Por exemplo, se a data for 31 de janeiro de 2019:

```
var d = new DateTime(2019, 1, 31);
d = d.AddMonths(1);
```

Ao somar 1 mês, o resultado *seria* 31 de fevereiro. Mas como fevereiro não tem 31 dias, a data é ajustada para o último dia do mês e o resultado é 28 de fevereiro de 2019 (se fosse em um ano bissexto, o resultado seria 29 de fevereiro).

---

Se você tem o valor do dia em uma variável separada (conforme [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/375986/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-verificar-se-muda-o-ano/376000#comment746690_376000)) e quer usar o mês e ano atual, basta fazer algo do tipo:

```
public DateTime obterData(string dia) {
    var d = Int32.Parse(dia);
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    // verificar se o valor do dia ultrapassa o último dia do mês
    var ultimoDia = DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, now.Month);
    if (d > ultimoDia) {
        d = ultimoDia;
    }
    return new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, d);
}

Data = obterData(contrato.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)).AddMonths(i - 1);
```

Mas se quiser pegar sempre o último dia do mês, pode criar outro método para fazer tal ajuste:

```
// soma os meses e obtém o último dia do mês resultante
public DateTime UltimoDia(DateTime data, int meses) {
    var d = data.AddMonths(meses);
    return new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month));
}

Data = UltimoDia(obterData(contrato.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2)), i - 1);
```

Mas você precisa decidir se vai sempre usar o último dia ou não. Por exemplo, se você começa do dia 30 de abril, vai querer que o próximo seja 30 ou 31 de maio? E quando chegar em fevereiro de 2020, será o dia 29, mas depois em março volta para 31 ou usa 29? Creio que aqui não há uma "função mágica", você que precisa decidir se vai usar o dia atual ou o último dia do mês.

Comment: Neste caso funciona pq ele pega o dia atual, porém este outro caso `Data = DateTime.Parse(contrato.DataCobranca.Substring(1, 2) + "/" + DateTime.Now.AddMonths(i).ToString("MM") + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"));` pega a substring para saber qual vai  gerar, ai não tem como colocar somente o `AddMonths(1)`

Comment: E entra também o caso, se for dia 31, teria que verificar qual o ultimo dia do mês para lançar, pois nem todo mês tem o dia 31

Comment: @marianac_costa Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Neste caso ele sempre pega o dia 30, mesmo o mês tendo 31. É possível pegar o dia 31 se o mês tiver ?

Comment: No caso se ele colocar T31, quer dizer que sempre vai ser o ultimo dia do mês, se tiver apenas 30 dias vai ser dia 30, se tiver 28 apenas, vai ser o 28.

Comment: @marianac_costa Esse T31 é um parâmetro/opção? Se for, basta adicionar um parâmetro na função `UltimoDia`, indicando se deve ajustar para o último dia do mês. Se não tiver que ajustar, basta retornar o resultado de `d.AddMonths(meses)`. Se tiver que ajustar, use o código acima (com `new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Year, d.Month))`).

Comment: Já fiz isso já, e funcionou certinho, obrigado pela ajuda e pela explicação.